# Nutch - Crawl a page for links, but don't index

Tags: solr, nutch

I would like to point a site to an index.html page to get it started, but don't want to include index.html in my search results- instead just having the child pages appear in the results. Is there a away to remove specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, the only solution I found to my problem, was to remove those URLs from the collection after is was crawled as a secondary step.